# Three.js: Trouble combining stencil clipping with EffectComposer

Tags: three.js, clipping, stencil-buffer, rendertarget

**NOTE: It appears I oversimplified my initial question. See below for the edit.**

I'm trying to combine the technique shown in the clipping/stencil example of Three.js, which uses the stencil buffer to render 'caps' when clipping geometry, with an EffectComposer-based rendering pipeline, but I am running into some difficulties. A fiddle demonstrating the problem can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/2vc76ajd/1/.

The EffectComposer has two passes: a RenderPass and a ShaderPass using CopyShader (see code below).

```
composer = new EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new RenderPass(scene, camera));
var shaderPass = new ShaderPass(CopyShader);
shaderPass.enabled = false;
composer.addPass(shaderPass);
```

The first renders the scene as usual, the latter merely copies the rendertarget onto a fullscreen quad. If I disable the ShaderPass everything works as intended: the geometry is clipped, and cutting planes are drawn in a different color:

[image]

When the ShaderPass is enabled by clicking the 'copy pass' checkbox in the upper right, however, the entire cutting plane gets rendered, rather than just the 'caps':

[image]

Presumably there is some interaction here between offscreen render targets and stencil buffers. However, I have so far been unable to find a way to have subsequent render passes look the same as the initial render. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

**EDIT**: While WestLangley's answer solved my initial problem, it unfortunately doesn't work when you're using an SSAOPass, which is what I was doing before trying to simplify the problem for the question. I have posted an updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/bavL98hf/1/, which includes the proposed fix and now toggles between a RenderPass or an SSAOPass. With SSAO turned on, the result is this:

[image]

I have tried setting stencilBuffer to true on all the render targets used in SSAOPass in addition to the ones in EffectComposer, but sadly that doesn't work this time. Can anyone tell me what else I am overlooking?

Comment: Enable the composer's stencil buffers: `composer.renderTarget1.stencilBuffer = true; composer.renderTarget2.stencilBuffer = true;`

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved it:

```
<EffectComposer stencilBuffer={true}>
should be something like this in vanilla:
composer.stencilBuffer = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**